# jQuery remove duplicate row(s) on output loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, sql

Im looking for some help with a jQuery script that will run when the results are output on the screen.

While running the output loop, I need jQuery to look at all the rows to see if a row with a similar ID already exists, if it does, then I need it remove the current row that was just output that has a duplicate id.

I am constructing my tr "id" by passing in a unique value from my db call and appeding it to "row_". So in the end it will make an id like "row_6373" (6373 being the unique value).

```
<table>
[while loop]
            // jQuery script is currently right here... 
    <tr id="row_6373"><td></td></tr>
    <tr id="row_988732"><td></td></tr>
    <tr id="row_6435"><td></td></tr>
    <tr id="row_6373"><td></td></tr> Row that was just output
[/while loop]
</table>
```

As the loop is running I need jQuery to check to see if row id "row_6373" exists, if it does I need it to remove the last instance of row_6373. This could happen several time in the output loop. "row_6373" could come up to be check a thousand times.

Right now I am doing this: I am running this at the beginning of the loop to see if the row id already exists, it is removing everything though.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    if($("#action_row_" + {{ action.product.id }}).length){
        $("#action_row_" + {{ action.product.id }}).remove();
    }
})
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have to show us the code that is actually building the table, otherwise we're just guessing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just testing to see if length is not undefined. And then you are removing all elements that match that selector. You want this:

```
$(function(){
    if($("#action_row_" + {{ action.product.id }}).length > 1){
        $("#action_row_" + {{ action.product.id }}).last().remove();
    }
})
```

Edit: Also should be using classes instead of id's if you're having duplicates: #action_row_ should be .action_row_

Comment: hmm, its not remove the row.

Comment: I should also point out that id's are supposed to be only used once on a page. You should be using a class for action_row_... And because you are using an ID, it will only return the first element it finds in jquery.

Comment: @LargeTuna actually you should eliminate duplicates in your query before laying them out in your page

Comment: I cant remove them, I have to have them because the way the other scripts work, trust me it has been a bear this is my last option. So basically i just need a script that will find duplicate "whatevers / class or ids" leave 1 row and remove the others. If you can help I would be so appreciative!